# Azure Media Services HLS Stream Url Change Resolution No Audio

Tags: azure, video-streaming, http-live-streaming, azure-media-services

Below is the manifest file get from Azure Media Services HLS Url.
The default HLS provided have Video and Audio, but when we try to change the resolution, it became only have Video but no Audio.

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-VERSION:7
#EXT-X-SESSION-KEY:METHOD=SAMPLE-AES,KEYFORMAT="com.apple.streamingkeydelivery",KEYFORMATVERSIONS="1",URI="skd://petronastownhallmedia.keydelivery.southeastasia.media.azure.net/FairPlay/?kid=4881e415-fb2d-45e4-a8dd-505a405cf93d"
#EXT-X-MEDIA:TYPE=AUDIO,GROUP-ID="audio",NAME="audio_und",LANGUAGE="und",DEFAULT=YES,AUTOSELECT=YES,CHANNELS="2",URI="QualityLevels(128000)/Manifest(audio_und,format=m3u8-aapl)"
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:BANDWIDTH=351536,RESOLUTION=340x192,CODECS="avc1.64000d,mp4a.40.5",AUDIO="audio"
QualityLevels(200000)/Manifest(video,format=m3u8-aapl)
#EXT-X-I-FRAME-STREAM-INF:BANDWIDTH=351536,RESOLUTION=340x192,CODECS="avc1.64000d",URI="QualityLevels(200000)/Manifest(video,format=m3u8-aapl,type=keyframes)"
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:BANDWIDTH=709236,RESOLUTION=384x216,CODECS="avc1.640015,mp4a.40.5",AUDIO="audio"
QualityLevels(550000)/Manifest(video,format=m3u8-aapl)
#EXT-X-I-FRAME-STREAM-INF:BANDWIDTH=709236,RESOLUTION=384x216,CODECS="avc1.640015",URI="QualityLevels(550000)/Manifest(video,format=m3u8-aapl,type=keyframes)"
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:BANDWIDTH=1015836,RESOLUTION=512x288,CODECS="avc1.640015,mp4a.40.5",AUDIO="audio"
QualityLevels(850000)/Manifest(video,format=m3u8-aapl)
#EXT-X-I-FRAME-STREAM-INF:BANDWIDTH=1015836,RESOLUTION=512x288,CODECS="avc1.640015",URI="QualityLevels(850000)/Manifest(video,format=m3u8-aapl,type=keyframes)"
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:BANDWIDTH=1526836,RESOLUTION=704x396,CODECS="avc1.64001e,mp4a.40.5",AUDIO="audio"
QualityLevels(1350000)/Manifest(video,format=m3u8-aapl)
#EXT-X-I-FRAME-STREAM-INF:BANDWIDTH=1526836,RESOLUTION=704x396,CODECS="avc1.64001e",URI="QualityLevels(1350000)/Manifest(video,format=m3u8-aapl,type=keyframes)"
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:BANDWIDTH=2395536,RESOLUTION=960x540,CODECS="avc1.64001f,mp4a.40.5",AUDIO="audio"
QualityLevels(2200000)/Manifest(video,format=m3u8-aapl)
#EXT-X-I-FRAME-STREAM-INF:BANDWIDTH=2395536,RESOLUTION=960x540,CODECS="avc1.64001f",URI="QualityLevels(2200000)/Manifest(video,format=m3u8-aapl,type=keyframes)"
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:BANDWIDTH=3724136,RESOLUTION=1280x720,CODECS="avc1.64001f,mp4a.40.5",AUDIO="audio"
QualityLevels(3500000)/Manifest(video,format=m3u8-aapl)
#EXT-X-I-FRAME-STREAM-INF:BANDWIDTH=3724136,RESOLUTION=1280x720,CODECS="avc1.64001f",URI="QualityLevels(3500000)/Manifest(video,format=m3u8-aapl,type=keyframes)"
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:BANDWIDTH=138976,CODECS="mp4a.40.5",AUDIO="audio"
QualityLevels(128000)/Manifest(audio_und,format=m3u8-aapl)
```

We have tried using / modified into following URL:

1. Have Audio but no video

   https://xxxx/c13459a8-065e-4d86-a2aa-c95f5ededafc/365a25ee-df07-4d1f-8679-0a029fccd397.ism/QualityLevels(128000)/Manifest(audio_und,format=m3u8-aapl)
2. No Audio no video

   https://xxxx/c13459a8-065e-4d86-a2aa-c95f5ededafc/365a25ee-df07-4d1f-8679-0a029fccd397.ism/QualityLevels(128000)/Manifest(video,audio_und,format=m3u8-aapl)

   https://xxxx/c13459a8-065e-4d86-a2aa-c95f5ededafc/365a25ee-df07-4d1f-8679-0a029fccd397.ism/QualityLevels(850000)/Manifest(video,format=m3u8-aapl,audiotrack=audio)

Any idea or suggestion regarding this issue?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

What player framework are you using?  Are you seeing this issue in HLS.js, Shaka player or in the Native iOS AVPlayer?

1. That is pointing to the audio only AAC track at 128Kbps.
2. The other tracks appear to include video and audio, so I'm not sure without testing those on my own. Which I can't do unless you submit a support ticket through the Azure portal and include the details on your account and streaming endpoint.  I suggest that path for faster support.

Comment: Using Native IOS AVPlayer currently

Comment: Did you get this working, If not file a support ticket with an example stream to have the support team look into your encoder details